Is there a way to download all of a user's answers?
It would be nice if it were possible to easily download all of a users answers, along with the question they are answering, in a nice format.
Is it possible?
Is it something that needs to be coded up or is it already possible with some sort of tool or feature?
If not, can I request this as a feature?

Have you seen https://data.stackexchange.com/

@DoubleAA yes, although I've only really used it for basic things, relying on others' code. Before I learn the whole api, might be worth double checking that it is possible. And in any case, I'd still be glad to find out there is a pre-existing way to do this :)

You can search for existing useful queries in the upper right box. Try searching something like "my answers" and see if you find anything that helps

@DoubleAA fantastico: https://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/1852375/my-answers

Might I recommend, then, that you post that as an answer, below?

@msh210 I will but it's not perfect yet. It gives it with HTML tags. Not ideal, will try to improve on it first
